# How to handle function in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to fetch data inside object, but my object shows whole function. Why doesn't it show only my return statement? What's the way to handle this problem?

```
const fetchContacts = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get(url, {
           headers: {
              'auth': 'asdsdfasfd'
           }
        }).then(resp => { 
            const newRows = resp && resp.data && resp.data.map(row => 
                ({
                    name: row.name,
                    surname: row.surname,
                    city: row.city,
                    familyNumber: async () => {
                        try {
                            const resp = await axios.get(url, {
                                headers: {
                                    'auth': 'asdsdfasfd'
                                }
                            })
                            return resp.data.length
                        } catch(error) {
                            return error
                        }
                    },
                })
            )
        })
    } catch(error) {
        return error
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but my object shows whole function"* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: My object contain something like this: 
familyNumber: ƒ familyNumber()

Comment: You only declared an anonymous function and assigned it to the key `familyNumber` but you never call it anywhere.

Comment: It shows the function because you are assigning the function to that property. If you want to assign the return value of the function instead you have to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `async/await`. You don't have to use the promise returned by `.then`. Try something like this. I haven't tested the code.

```
const fetchContacts = async () => {
    try {

       const resp =  await axios.get(url, {
           headers: {
              'auth': 'asdsdfasfd'
           }
        });

        const resNo = await axios.get(url2, {
                                headers: {
                                    'auth': 'somethingNew-qednken'
                                }
                            });


         const newRows = resp.data && resp.data.map(row => 
                ({
                    name: row.name,
                    surname: row.surname,
                    city: row.city,
                    familyNumber: resNo.data.length || 0
                })
            );

        //console.log("my newRows : ", newRows);

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```